# adding multiple options to listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page where I need to allow user to add multiple options like this

Text box (type here and click add)
Listbox  ( added to listbox)

Does ajaxcontrol toolkit has any such control ?

Please suggest

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.

Comment: If you are looking to add list items to a listbox on clicking add, surely listbox can do that. You only have to call listBox.Items.Add(yourItem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to add list items to a listbox on clicking add, surely listbox can do that. You only have to call listBox.Items.Add(yourItem)

If you are looking for all that in one control, no, it does not have that sort of a control. 
But it should be fairly easy to make a user control or custom control that did that.

On the textchange event or add button click, create a new ListItem and add it to the list of Items.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to add an item to a `ListBox`, or any web control that implements a `DataSource` and `ItemCollection` for the matter.

### Option 1 - DataSource

```
private List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Items { get; set; }

protected AddItem(string text, string value)
{
    this.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(value, text))

    this.ListBox.ValueTextField = "Key";
    this.ListBox.DataTextField = "Value";
    this.ListBox.DataSource = this.Items;
    this.ListBox.DataBind;
}
```

It's worth noting that in option 1 I've used a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` rather than a `Dictionary<string, string>` as a list box can have items with duplicate values.

### Option 2 - Items.Add()

```
protected AddItem(string text, string value)
{
    var listItem = new ListItem(text, value);
    this.ListBox.Items.Add(listItem);
}
```